# TortoiseSvn symbolic links to seperate folder in repository

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Im not sure if the title describes what I am asking well but Ill give it a shot here:

**What I have**
-MySvnRepository
+    Project One Folder
+    Project Two Folder
-     Shared File Folder
-        ToolkitDefinitions.cs

**What I am looking for**
-MySvnRepository
-    Project One Folder
-        Symoblic link to ToolkitDefinitions.cs
-    Project Two Folder
-        Symoblic link to ToolkitDefinitions.cs
-     Shared File Folder
-        ToolkitDefinitions.cs

The point is I have a DLL I am maintaining in which I want my coworkers to have the latest versions without having seprate copies in Project 1, Project 2, Project 3... etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand you right, but I think what you want can be done using externals: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: That looks like what I want, well I wanted it at the file level but i can deal with directories. Is there a way to do it with Repo Browser or do I need to use a shell? If you make your comment an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand you right, but I think what you want can be done using externals - at least on a directory level, not for files though.

See the [chapter in the SVN book.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html)

I've never tried using externals  pointing to the same repo, but according to the examples in the manual, it's possible.

You can do it in TortoiseSVN by going to a working copy, right-clicking the directory you want to create the external in, editing the properties, and adding the externals definition(s). Then commit the change. The external will be pulled on the next time you update the working copy.

Comment: It is possible to define "file externals". Externals can be in same repository; in that case you should use a relative path when you define the externals.

Comment: @Stefan how would I do file externals? The manual seems clear on the issue: `An externals definition can point only to directories, not to files.` - is there a workaround? If there is, I'd be interested how it works.

Comment: you need version 1.6... the only information I could find right now is here (at the bottom): http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

Comment: apparently file externals have to be in the same repository